# Mail.app, BCC, and smart filters that match "Any Recipient"

Tags: email, osx-lion

It appears that Mail.app "Any Recipient" filters do not match BCC addresses on OS X Lion.  Are there any known workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one. My fix was to get Indev's MailTags ($30) and then use the "Edit Header List..." option -- so helpfully added by MailTags under Apple Mail's Rules -- to add Bcc to the default To/From/Cc/Subject list.

Then create a top-level rule to tag all Bcc's to whomever with a MailTags keyword, and then use that tag in combination with "Any Recipient" and "Include messages from Sent" in the appropriate Smart Mailbox in order to catch all Bcc's to those persons from my Sent folder.

I hope this is clear and I hope it helps.

P.S. I'm on Snow Leopard, in the process of trying to buff up Apple's Mail app before tearing myself away from Eudora. I haven't tried this in Lion or Mountain Lion, but I don't think Mail ever had the built-in ability to filter for outgoing Bcc's. Indev's offerings (MailTags and MailActOn) seem really solid, and they are both available for OS X 10.6 - 10.8.